# scaleX increasing automatically in keyframes

Tags: html, css

In this example it is clear why the `grow` animation works:

```
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  } 
}
```

However, why does it also work in the below code snippet?

```css
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      position: relative;
      animation: grow 5s;
    }
    
    @keyframes grow {
      0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
      }
       
    }
```

```html
 
<body>    
<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>
    
<div></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation starts with the requested value but ends with the default value which is without the transform property